# Arguing that Graph, $G$, is 3 regular and pairwise edge-disjoint path can't share internal vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph that is 3-regular. There are $n$ pairwise edge-disjoint $x,y$ paths. I want to show "since G is 3 regular, these paths cannot share internal vertices." I know the answer is supposed to be because it would force four distinct edges at a vertex. What I don't see is the argument that forces me to this conclusion.

Comment: What is known about n ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: what happens if two of the n paths do indeed share internal vertices? What happens at that vertex?

Comment: At the shared vertex, there is an edge from some path P and another one from P1. How does this help?

Comment: If it's an internal vertex, each path would contribute two edges to the vertex.

Comment: So why is this a problem?

Comment: If two paths which are edge distinct share a internal vertex, each path would contribute two distinct edges to that vertex, and there would be a total of 4 distinct edges adjacent to that vertex.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being dense. But why would each path would contribute two edges to the internal vertex?

Comment: Consider the shared vertex and label it v. For the first path, since v is an internal vertex, it is adjacent to two edges (one into v, one out of v) For the second path, v is also an internal vertex, so it is adjacent to two edges (one into v, one out of v). The two edges from the first path are distinct and the two edges from the second path are also distinct. Furthermore, the two edges from the first path are distinct from the two edges from the second path, since the paths mentioned are edge disjoint.

Comment: The confusion here may be over the word "internal". An internal vertex of a path is one which is adjacent to two vertices in the path, as opposed to the two vertexes at the ends which are only adjacent to 1 other vertex.